# Variation of Thomae's Function

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

So, I have this hard question and I haven't got a clue how to start. I know I might use the Pigeonhole Principle, but anyways, it goes as follows:

**First** we need to define:

1. $$\{\frac{p_n}{q_n} \}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}=\mathbb{Q} \cap (0,1),\qquad {p_n} , {q_n}\quad \text{coprimes} $$
2. 

$$\quad\{y_n\}_n \subset\mathbb{Q} \cap (0,1)\quad \text{where we only know}\quad y_n \to 0 \quad \text{with large n}$$

3. 

$$\quad r´: [0,1] \to [0,1], \quad r´(x)=
\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if $x=0$} \\
0, & \text{if $x \in \mathbb{R- Q}$}
\\y_n,& \text{if $x=\frac{p_n}{q_n}$}
\end{cases} $$

so, finally, **find $y_n$ for which r´ is differentiable in infinitely many irrationals**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I think if we define $y_n=\min\{1/n,1/q_n^3\}$ it would be differentiable on every quadratic algebraic number. Let $x$ be such a number. By Liouville's theorem we would have for some constant $C$ that:
$$|x-\frac{p}{q}|>\frac{C}{q^2}$$
for every $p,q\in\mathbb{Z}$. Thus:
$$|\frac{r(x)-r(p/q)}{x-p/q}|<\frac{q^2r(p/q)}{C}\leq\frac{1}{Cq} $$
When we take the limit $p/q\rightarrow x$ we'll have that $q\rightarrow \infty$, thus the Newton's quoeficient will go to zero. Clearly, when we are approaching by non-rational numbers the coeficient will still be 0, thus the limit exist.